# hidden selenium browser py

Tags: python, selenium

how can i hidden selenium browser while it running

i have this code

```
def init_driver(self):
        options = Options()
        options = Options()
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        # options.add_argument("--window-size=400,400")
        options.add_argument("--incognito")
        options.add_argument("--log-level=0")
        options.add_argument("--log-level=1")
        options.add_argument("--log-level=2")
        options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            options=options, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        return driver
```

so i wanna when it run it show the browser the i wanna it to hidden after get the page

this code

```
def hiden_brow(self):
    self.driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    options.headless = True
```

Comment: Not possible you need to create a new instance of driver. The options will persist for the lifetime of the WebDriver and be uneditable.

Answer (score 0):

either `options.add_argument(--headless)`
or set the `options.headless = True` under the `options.add_argument("--log-level=3")`
then it should work.